# Intuitive utility of the Jeffreys prior, eg. in Bernoulli trials

Tags: statistics, intuition, statistical-inference, bayesian, bernoulli-distribution

I understand the computation the Jeffreys prior, and also its [historical motivation](https://www2.stat.duke.edu/courses/Fall11/sta114/jeffreys.pdf). I (somewhat) understand the theoretical desirability of a "prior-construction principle/method" that is invariant under monotone parameter transformation, and non-informative.

However, I am having difficulties translating this to how we can use it in real applications. For example, in an unfair coin with unknown heads-probability $\theta$, why *should* I use Jeffreys prior, which is a $Beta(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2})$ distribution favouring the extremes of either heads or tails?

It seems to me that, in order to satisfy this theoretical need for parameter-invariance, we say that the "best" prior assumption is that the coin is either entirely heads-biased or tails-biased? Why is this the "best"?

**My guess at an intuition**: Perhaps the answer lies in the Fisher information and the concept of "non-informativeness"? In the sense that if our prior for $\theta$ is high at the extremes, then any incoming data will give us more information about $\theta$.

For instance, if given some prior where $p(\theta)$ is high around $0.1$, then a Heads will drastically change our posterior. But if another prior has $p(\theta)$ high around 0.5, then a Heads won't change the posterior as much. As the latter posterior offers less "information" per data point, we would prefer a model where $p(0.1)>p(0.5)$ (which is something the Jeffreys prior satisfies) in order to maximise the information we bring in from the data.

Is the above a reasonable intuition? Does anyone have a better explanation?

Comment: Pragamatic arguments include this Jeffreys prior being symmetric (so too are the uniform prior and Haldane prior) and proper (as is the uniform prior but not the Haldane prior), while avoiding part of the push towards the middle from the uniform prior.  The invariance to reparametrisation under smooth monotone transformation is a bonus: the problem is that there is no "non-informative" prior but arbitrarily using a uniform prior would  raise the next  question as to whether $\theta$ or $\frac1{\theta}$   or $\log(\frac{\theta}{1-\theta})$ or something else should have a uniform distribution.

Comment: Non-informative prior distributions do not exist. A non-informative prior is not a distribution. This is just a function which, via a formal application of Bayes' theorem, yields a posterior distribution which aims to reflect as best as possible the information brought by the data. You must not interpret a non-informative prior as a distribution. So this Jeffreys prior does not favour anything.